# All thread are getting lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

After acquiring the lock,the thread should sleep for certain time(6000ms in this case) preventing another thread from acquiring lock.It is working properly when i'm using `l1.lock()` method,but when i'm using `l1.tryLock()` or `l1.tryLock(1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECOND)`, both thread are acquiring lock before previous thread releases the lock.How is it possible?

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

class MyLocks implements Runnable {
  static Lock l1;

  public static void main(String... asd) {
    l1 = new ReentrantLock();
    MyLocks obj = new MyLocks();
    new Thread(obj).start();
    new Thread(obj).start();
  }

  public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is try to acquire lock");
    try {
      l1.trylock();
     // only those thread which has acquired lock will get here. 
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has acquired lock");

      Thread.sleep(6000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    l1.unlock();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake is to call a method and ignore the result. Most likely you are running

```
lock.tryLock(); // notice this ignores whether the lock was obtained or not.
```

when you should be doing something like

```
while(!lock.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.SECOND)) {
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - Couldn't get lock, waiting");
}
```

note: Don't discard exceptions unless you are very confident they don't matter.

```
}catch(Exception e){} // something when wrong but lets pretend it didn't
```

For some tips on how to handle Exceptions.

https://vanilla-java.github.io/2016/06/21/Reviewing-Exception-Handling.html

Comment: When using lock.tryLock(),if another thread holds the lock,then it will return "false", but it should not be able to acquire the lock as another thread has not unlock it

Comment: Additionally, you should put the `unlock()` in a `finally` block, so that the JVM guarantees it to be called.

Comment: the thing i'm not able to understand is that how both thread are able to acquire the lock at the same time?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38520943/edit) the question to show how you are using `tryLock()`.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz The two threads are _not_ both able to acquire the lock at the same time.  One of them acquires the lock, prints its name, and then sleeps for six seconds.  The other one _fails_ to acquire the lock, prints its name, and then sleeps for six seconds.  The `tryLock()` method returns immediately regardless of whether or not it was able to acquire the lock.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz You can't because your not.  Like I said in my answer "A common mistake is to call a method and ignore the result." which what you are doing. I have also given you what you must do to correct it.